# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException while debugging in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I'm developing servlet web application in Eclipse JavaEE.
The application successfully deployed and started on local Tomcat server.

When I started the application in Eclipse in debug mode on the same server I've got the exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'MedexamDC': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/MedexamDC] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:779)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:495)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:767)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1347)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/MedexamDC] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:817)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:173)
at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:163)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:155)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:179)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:104)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:106)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:231)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:217)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
... 36 more

мар 07, 2017 4:32:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet mvc-dispatcher
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/MedexamDC] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:817)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:173)
at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:163)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:155)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:179)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:104)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:106)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:231)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:217)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:779)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:495)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:767)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1347)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

File conf/context.xml

```
<Context reloadable="true">
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1" name="jdbc/MedexamDC" password="123" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/medexam" username="postgres"/>
</Context>
```

webapp\META_INF\context.xml

```
<Context>
  <Context path=""/>
  <ResourceLink type="javax.sql.DataSource" name="jdbc/MedexamDC" global="jdbc/MedexamDC" />    
</Context>
```

I'm out of possible reasons for this. Anyone has any suggestion? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be happening because you are not using the physical installation of Tomcat, but a "copy" of it, which is the default option for Eclipse.

If you look on your `Project Explorer` view, you will see there is a `Servers` project. Look into it and find the Tomcat you are using.

Inside of that Tomcat folder, you will see a set of configuration files. These are the files that Eclipse uses to boot your Tomcat, so you can pllay with them without ruining your physical installation.

All you have to do is opening the `context.xml` file inside the Tomcat folder, which is inside of `Servers`, and paste the `Resource` you already have on `conf/context.xml`

After restarting your Tomcat, it should work fine.

Another option is to tell Eclipse to use the physical installation. you can do that on the `Servers` view. Double click your Tomcat to open its configuration, and at bottom-left side you will see 3 options. Select "Use Tomcat installation" to take over on the physical installation, which is already configured.

Comment: First option doesn't work for me. And second is OK. Thank you!